# Is there a list anywhere of known or hypothetical hypernuclei?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, standard-model, binding-energy, exotic-matter

Does anyone have resources that include a list or set of descriptions of [hypernuclei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypernucleus) that been observed, or been proven to be possible hypothetically? Is it possible, even, that there is something like a periodic table of hyperelements?

Comment: try this https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2018.0145 . I do not know if this google  link will open for you. it is a talk by the same author with a lot of details https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwip0b6hgZz-AhU0XvEDHTa1Ah8QFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ggi.infn.it%2Ftalkfiles%2Fslides%2Ftalk3205.pdf&usg=AOvVaw26YeRo_lvzogiR5rS1H1w6